# How does the home button or volume up/down button works (Android)? Does pressing this button generates a hardware interrupt?

Tags: android, smartphone, interrupt-handling, android-hardware, hardware

I was wondering how does the home button or volume up/down button works in Android? Does pressing this button generates a hardware interrupt?

I would like to execute a piece of code with higher privilege (in kernel) by pressing this home/volume key. Is it possible? Any pointers?

if pressing these button generates a hardware interrupt, I think I have to modify the interrupt handler to execute the code I want to execute. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU: // Menu button
            doSomething();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME: // Home button
            doSomething();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: //  Volume Up key
            doSomething();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: // Volume Down key
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

You can find more keys [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).